# GeoServer WPS Chaining problem

Tags: geoserver, xml, wps

I have a bit of a problem with WPS(1.0) chaining on GeoServer (2.9.1.).
I am following this tutorial for
http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/wps/chaining_processes.html
Chain 1: Extract the rivers into the “restricted areas” polygons
Problem is in the third step, when I am choosing SUBPROCESS of gs:CollectGeometries, input XML looks empty

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0"service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier/>
  <wps:DataInputs/>
  <wps:ResponseForm/>
</wps:Execute>
```

It has no input at all, and execute of the process will end up with ErrorMessage 
"Failed to parse process inputs"
It happens not only with this example, but with all the chaining
[image: Settings of WPS chaining]

This is the whole XML from process inputs/outputs

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>gs:Clip</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:sf="http://www.openplans.org/spearfish">
            <wfs:Query typeName="sf:streams"/>
          </wfs:GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>clip</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wps" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS">
            <ows:Identifier/>
            <wps:DataInputs/>
            <wps:ResponseForm/>
          </wps:Execute>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

Comment: please add the whole WPS xml file for us to look at

Comment: I just added whole XML request

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm it's an issue. It's probably a side effect of the Wicket 7 migration. I'd open a bug report at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/issues

Comment: Was this problem ever fixed? Iam experiencing same issues using version 2.10.2

Comment: its still not fixed

Comment: I have the same problem with all proccess chaining.
It never works.

Comment: has this never been solved?

Comment: No. Chaining works fine when XML requests are issued, but the request builder does not work. There is little reason to fix it, it's used for demos but never for actual paid work. If you know someone that can do a fix, or sponsor a fix, send them to the devel list or the commercial support page.