# Storing GeoServer WPS result as a new layer

Tags: geoserver, wps

Is it possible to store the result of a WPS process as a new layer without writing my own plugin in Java? I know there's a /tmp folder inside /data, but how can I grab it and publish as a new layer using the GeoServer webgui?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `gs:import` process as described in [this blog post](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/wps/chaining_processes.html#geoserver-direct-data-integration-and-store-back-capabilities-through-gs-import), simply specify the process you are using as a sub process in the input parameter of the import process.

Comment: I'm trying to use the subprocess function (define/edit) with a simple JST:Buffer, but the autogenerated code is bugged, the xml scheme is empty. (GeoServer 2.90/Tomcat 7)

Comment: I have the same problem: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213300/geoserver-wps-chaining-problem/213385